# How do I install Widevine in the Iridium Browser?

Tags: browser, netflix

I can't find Widevine in the Chrome Web Store,
or even a download for it.
It is required for Netflix.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I install Widevine in the Iridium Browser?

You can't – for privacy reasons.
[The Widevine extension, required by Netflix,

doesn't comply with the privacy standards of the Iridium Browser](https://iridiumbrowser.de/faq).

I haven't (knowingly) used the Widevine extension, but I believe it
is built-in in Google Chrome.
(I can confirm that Widevine isn't available in the Chrome Web Store.)